# Jquery/Javascript Click and Hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, click

I have a series of cells that when clicked get cloned and appended to a seperate table (of one row). When cells are clicked on in this second table they return to where they were in the previous table (or rather they get removed and the original cell fadesTo solid. However I need the cells in this second table (the `#answertable` to be `.sortable()`. I can move them around find, but as as soon as I let go, the original on click function gets executed and the cell disappears.

Answertable sortable code:

```
$(function () {
  $("#answertable tr").sortable();
  $("#answertable tr").disableSelection();
});
```

Relevant cells code (the `fadeOut()` bit really):

```
$(answertablecells).click(function(){
    var num = $(this).attr("id");
    for(var i=12; i < num.length; i++) {
      var nums = num.substr(i, i++, i++);
    }               
    $('#in_answerbox' + nums + "a").fadeTo('fast', 1).removeAttr('id');
    $(this).fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('id').remove();
});
```

I need all of the above to run when you click on it, but not when you sortable. Basically I want the hold to cancel the on click event but not the sortable event.

Any suggestions? All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the duration of the click and call the fadeout function if the duration is less than some value i.e. (250ms):

```
function myfunction(){
    var num = $(this).attr("id");
    for(var i=12; i < num.length; i++) {
        var nums = num.substr(i, i++, i++);
    }               
    $('#in_answerbox' + nums + "a").fadeTo('fast', 1).removeAttr('id');
    $(this).fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('id').remove();
}

var longpress = false, startTime, endTime;

$(answertablecells).on('click', function (e) {
    if (!longpress) myfunction();
});

$(answertablecells).on('mousedown', function () {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
});

$(answertablecells).on('mouseup', function () {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();
    longpress = (endTime - startTime < 250) ? false: true;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/ERUXN/)

Comment: Perfect. With a bit of context specific editing this now works. Thanks for the jsfiddle as well. I was wondering though if setTimeout() could be used in this context too?

Comment: yup it should work fine, you can add it after `if(!longpress){` if you want it to be executed after longpress or add it after `else{` to be executed after shortpress i.e. `if(!longpress){do something after shortpress}else{do something else after longpress}`